# How to test on different emulators for 2015 and 2016 models for samsung tizen tv?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I had submitted a tizen tv app, some defects had been raised specific to 2015 and 2016 models. In the emulator manager , I can see just one emulator for HD1080TV and platform tv-samsung-public-2.4, I am not sure if this is the VM for 2015 or 2016 model, and can't find a way to download additional VMs. How can I proceed to resolve these defects provided I do not have a wherewithal to buy both the samsung tvs ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will get more precise answer from following community
https://www.samsungdforum.com/

https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumDashBoard/c305cb96c72a9e5b